# Laravel Forge Queues not firing

Tags: queue, laravel-forge

In my Forge server I go to Queues and check the worker status, which always shows `RUNNING`.

However, when pushing a job onto the queue it never fires, yet when I SSH into the server and run `php artisan queue:listen` it does.

This on L 5.4 with two new Forge load balanced servers. I've restarted the workers, deleted them and created new ones... I've even restarted the servers, but no joy.

Do I have to manually start the queues in Artisan?

---

Here's my `config/queue.php`

```
'beanstalkd' => [
    'driver' => 'beanstalkd',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'queue' => 'default',
    'retry_after' => 90,
],
```

My `.env`

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=beanstalkd
```

The Forge Queue Worker Status

```
worker-124625:worker-124625_00   RUNNING   pid 17929, uptime 13:52:44
```

Forge Queue settings

[image]
<sub>(source: [pbrd.co](https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/aybRalw8W.jpg))</sub>

Nothing is out of the ordinary... I don't think...

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same issue with SQS.

Comment: @JackBarham No. In fact I continued having problems so I switched to Redis for queues and haven't looked back.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks.

Comment: Redis queue not even working for me but database queue is and I'd love to know why Redis is not working for me on Laravel forge